# No CameraInfo received using Rviz

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get camera data from the turtlebot to my workstation.  The netbook is running 10.04 and the workstation laptop is running 10.10.

On the turtlebot netbook I configured the IP settings, and ran the teleop successfully. I would like to now grab camera data from the turtlebot kinect.

On the netbook I ran

> rosrun turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch

On the turtlebot workstation I run

> rosrun rviz rviz

I click add, camera, then under the display bar, under Camera, it says "Status Warning." Image Topic I select camera>rgb>Image_raw. I get an error and No CameraInfo received on [/camera_info]

I have tried not only Image_raw, but a few of the other selections, and non of them seem to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62645/no-camerainfo-received-using-rviz/) by [djchase88](https://answers.ros.org/users/4883/djchase88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-07-08**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/29298/turtlebot-kinect-fails-since-dropped-10000-of-messages-and-wireless-crashed/     you can have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That suggests that the cameara is not streaming data.  Make sure it's breaker is powered on and the kinect.launch does not have any errors.

You can also explore what's being published using rostopic echo and rostopic hz

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djchase88](https://answers.ros.org/users/4883/djchase88/) on 2013-05-15**:
all breakers are powered on